# Functionally, how do drag and drop page builders work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on my first extensive MERN project and part of the functionality involves specific components (like a checkbox to-do list, images, text, ets...) that then allow the user to build out different pages, larger multi-checkbox aggregation lists, etc... Think of it as something like https://www.notion.so/notes.

Building the individual react components and configuring them on static pages is straightforward. However, I'm having a hard time conceptually understanding how to take those components and then dynamically allow users to build out custom pages using them.

In a broad sense, how do page builders functionally work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a broad idea. You will need a page where the left side lists all your UI components [thump nails] and the right side area for dragging and dropping those compoents. You will need a grid system with rows and columns components like Bootstrap Grid or MUI Grid dividing space into 12 portions for the layout of any page. You should let each dropped component give an option to accept its props so users can set it. Setting props can be another component.

When they save the design you should get the react component tree of what they are saving along with all properties and save it in your DB. You should be able to generate both the design view and the actual view with those saved data.

It was easy to say but I know it's a lot of work. I have seen similar work done using Angular and .NET.